# Is there a word for words with specific meaning?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

A word that group words that give the impression "There is a word for that!" and "*Mot juste*" is what I inquire. I can't find any term for it, and my search of the list only leads to a website like http://phrontistery.info/

A word for a list of words such as cajole and desiderium. I am not asking about words that have specific meaning, I am asking whether those words have a name that group them together.

Another way to see it, some words exist in dictionaries but not in thesaurus, what those words are named is my question.

Comment: What is wrong with 'mot juste' - [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mot_juste) **mot juste** (plural mots justes). The perfectly appropriate word or phrase for the situation.  Definitely English ('Borrowing from French'); arguably a word (compound noun) [ [eg Macmillan:](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/mot-juste)] NOUN [COUNTABLE].

Comment: Frederick, do you mean "Words with only one meaning?"  Is "quarter" a word with specific meaning, or does the fact that it has more than one meaning exclude it from the set you have in mind?

Comment: @TimRomano  "... the fact that it has more than one meaning..." does exclude it from the set in my mind. Thanks for clarifying it

Comment: When you find a word without a specific meaning let me know. All words have meanings, or they aren't words!

Comment: @curiousdannii "all words have meanings", I believe _most_ words have multiple meanings, used for multiple contexts. But _some_ words have **a** meaning only. When I refers to those words as _specific_ I mean you can't find a word to substitute it without reducing or replacing the meaning.

Comment: Hi Frederick.  You give the examples of cajole and desiderium.  Were those meant to be anti-examples?  Those have **many, many, very obvious close synonyms.**  So it's difficult to see what you mean??

Answer (score 0):

"What's that crawling on my back?"

"I believe it is *latrodectus variolus*."

"Don't give me ***the scientific term*** - just GET IT OFF!"

Comment: My question refers to the collection of those mot juste words. Not the words itself.

Comment: Those words could be called *terms*.   Although a term is a word with a specific meaning in some contexts, though it may have other meanings in different contexts.

Comment: @TimRomano It does cover the "specific meaning" part, but the need of context negate it. The specific words ideally need no context at all, because it only has one and only meaning.